What is a pre-commit hook that formats markdown in quarto (qmd) files?
I use the style-files pre-commit filter to style Quarto (qmd) files, but it only formats my R code, not the markdown.
Is there something that formats the markdown?  For example, line wrapping.
Quarto markdown is pandoc markdown.
